# Is there a way to edit username and email via code in android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I was wondering if there was a way to edit the name and email via code in Android Studio, to change it in Cloud Firestore. I made a program where it only changes the name in real-time and when logged off, and logged in again it changes back to the previous one which is in Cloud Firestore.

`vardas` is an `EditText` field in the app design.

My code:

```
public void updateProfile(final View view) {

    view.setEnabled(false);

    vardas1 = vardas.getText().toString();

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    UserProfileChangeRequest request = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
            .setDisplayName(vardas1)
            .build();

    firebaseUser.updateProfile(request)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    view.setEnabled(true);
                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Sėkmingai atnaujintas profilis", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    view.setEnabled(true);
                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ", e.getCause());
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Unable to understand.

Comment: are you want to update username into firestore

Comment: @MUFAzmi Yes. I have code that it shows in my program what i have in my firestore, it displays both name and email in editable text boxes. But i want that when i change that username or email in those boxes, to change also in the cloud firestore

Comment: @MUFAzmi Why even ask about the problem if you won't answer after i responded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if there was a way to edit the name and email via code in Android Studio, to change it in Cloud Firestore.

Yes, there is. According to the official documentation regarding [how to update a document in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data):

> To update some fields of a document without overwriting the entire document, use the update() method.

Assuming you want to update the name and email of the authenticated user that exists at the following reference:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = rootRef.collection("users");
DocumentReference uidRef = usersRef.document(uid);
```

Try the following lines of code:

```
uidRef.update(
              "name", "John",
              "email", "john@email.com"
             ).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!");
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Error updating document", e);
    }
});
```

The result of using this is code, is the update of the name property with "John".

What you are doing in your code is nothing else than updating the name in the FirebaseUser object. That operation is not related in any way with Firestore. So updating the FirebaseUser it doesn't mean that the user will be also updated in the Firestore database. There are two different separate operations that are not related.

Comment: No, you should definitely not call this code twice, you should simply pass the other property and its value to the same `update()` method, as in my updated answer. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: One more question, if i would like to add authentication by hand of a user, would i need to disable the Firebase authentication and how to do that?

Comment: No, you should simply implement [Firebase authentication with email and password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth).

Comment: I mean this work is for my college. And teacher asked that i would implement my own authentication, not the automatic one that Firebase gives

Comment: I that case, you should implement your own mechanism for that but you'll have much to work.